# how to replace lowercase letters with an other character?

Tags: java, string

is there an easier way to replace lowercase letters with another character like a dot
i'm currently using this code

```
        s = s.replace("a", ".");s = s.replace("b", ".");s = s.replace("c", ".");s = s.replace("d", ".");s = s.replace("e", ".");s = s.replace("f", ".");s = s.replace("g", ".");s = s.replace("h", ".");s = s.replace("i", ".");s = s.replace("j", ".");s = s.replace("k", ".");s = s.replace("l", ".");s = s.replace("m", ".");s = s.replace("n", ".");s = s.replace("o", ".");s = s.replace("p", ".");s = s.replace("q", ".");s = s.replace("r", ".");s = s.replace("s", ".");s = s.replace("t", ".");s = s.replace("u", ".");s = s.replace("v", ".");s = s.replace("w", ".");s = s.replace("x", ".");s = s.replace("y", ".");s = s.replace("z", ".");
```

Comment: Posting as a comment, not an answer: if you use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), this is just `CharMatcher.JAVA_LOWER_CASE.replaceFrom(s, '.')`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it in much simpler way using [`String#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method, which takes a Regex as first parameter: -

```
s = s.replaceAll("[a-z]", ".");
```

`[a-z]` is a character class with `range` which matches every character from `a` to `z`. So, all lowercase letters are replaced with `.`

Answer (score 2):

Out of the 4 variants of `replace()` method of String, you can bet on `replaceAll()`

**Eg:**

```
public class Replace {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        String s = "HELLO THIs Is a BIG gAme";

        System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[a-z]","." ));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to do the replacement.

```
   s.replaceAll("[a-z]",".");
```

Answer (score 1):

Old style replacement:

```
public class Replace{   
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s= "HEllo WOrlD";
    char replacement='.';

    char[] c =s.toCharArray();

    for(int i =0;i<s.length();i++) {
        for(int j=97;j<=122;j++) {
            if(s.charAt(i)==j)
                c[i]=replacement;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(s);      
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(c));  
}
}
```